# GUI tool For PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Goal:
User PowerShell in a user-friendly approach

Problem:
I have seen PowerShell using for MS-dos but there is not tool such as Visual studio as PowerShell? Any softeware with GUI for PowerShell with purpose to faciliate the coding approach?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) is the best GUI tool for PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

> Windows PowerShell ISE

[image]
to write PowerShell commands in a user friendly manner. Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: PowerShell ISE 3 is great, but unfortunately does not works with SP 2010 :'(

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the version of SharePoint you are targeting. If you want to write scripts for SharePoint 2010, you will have to stick to an editor that use .Net 3.5.

If you use any editor that runs with .Net 4 or later, you won't be able to use SharePoint commands. This is due to the SharePoint [limitation that make it not works with .Net 4](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40654/sharepoint-with-net-4-0).

As I'm running SP2010 on a Windows 2012 R2 server, I can't use PowerShell ISE (which is great with W2012!).

I fallback to [PowerShell Plus](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/powershellplus), because it does not requires .Net. I only have to tweak the configuration file of the soft (`C:\Program Files\Idera\PowerShellPlus\PowerShellPlus.exe.config`). I forced the program to works on .Net 2.0 runtime:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a GUI app use [PowerShell Studio 2012](http://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) by sapien, i created many PowerShell GUI App using this IDE

and if you want an IDE for coding and debugging use [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) its amazing or ISE from Microsoft